# I need help: how to describe a Chinese LOGO without the picture

Tags: translation, characters

I am helping a liquor(baijiu) brand translate some materials for design competitions in UK, and I met difficulties when describing the details of the LOGO design.

[image]

In the picture is a part of the brand LOGO, it is a Chinese character 安 (an1), and inside the Chinese character, the part 女 is designed to look like a Chinese liquor cup.

（女 is a Chinese character component of 安, 女 means women, but here I'm not really describing women. Our products are for adults in all genders. The design of cup in 女 because the shape of this component is suitable for making a liquor cup shape.）

The Chinese description is 古代酒杯构成的艺术字“安"

My translation :  *A Chinese liquor cup is contained in the character An.*

After I finished the translation, the file was sent to some friends to help check. One of them reported that the sentence was confusing, they can't understand.

I really need help. I don’t think I can use any Chinese characters in the translation. The pictures may not be displayed together with the text. Or the judges may not know much about Chinese culture.

How should I describe it without the picture or using Chinese characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you post your Chinese description, I could perhaps help with the English translation!

The Chinese character 安 ān shows a woman 女 nǔ under a roof 宀  mián

安 ān has many meanings. The main meanings are peaceful, tranquil, quiet, safe.

In the logo, the woman has been replaced with the representation of an ancient Chinese wine cup, 爵 jué

> 爵是中国古代一种用于盛放、斟倒和加热酒的容器。爵在商代和的西周青铜器的考古发现中是非常常见的。

The meaning of the logo is maybe: a housewife may peacefully enjoy her "Schnapps" in the safety of her home!

Or maybe that is not what is meant?? I don't know many women who drink 白酒!

古代酒杯构成的艺术字“安"

35 words:

The logo represents an ancient, three-legged, bronze Chinese wine cup, 爵 jué, under a roof, 宀 mián, and resembles the common Chinese character 安 ān, which carries the main meanings of peaceful, tranquil, quiet, safe.

Comment: Yes, my Chinese description is 古代酒杯构成的艺术字“安”. The numbers of words are limited in 250 words and there are still many long sentences in the whole material so I need it to be short. 女 is a Chinese character component of 安, and that liquor cup is 爵. But I am not sure if the judges know about Chinese culture, so I want to give a rough description of it, don't need to analyze the component of "安" or explaining in detail "爵". use “Chinese liquor cup” as 爵

Comment: 女 is a Chinese character component of 安, 女 means women, but here I'm not really describing women. Our products are for adults in all genders. The design of cup in 女 because the shape of this component is suitable for making a liquor cup shape.

Answer (score 1):

Although you are not describing "女", I think the words related to the shape of the cup will draw attention and curiosity from the judges :)

- The logo features/consists of a female-shaped win/liquor cup contained in the Chinese character/letter, (that means peaceful, tranquil, or quiet,) "An".